# The excess of an integer $n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

How can one find an estimate for $$\sum_{p \text{ prime,}\ k\geq 2:p^k|n}1$$ The reason is to show that the normal value of $\Omega(n)$ is $\log\log n$, the same as that of $\omega(n)$.

Comment: This is the number of primes smaller than $\sqrt{n}$. By PNT, it is $\Omega (\log \sqrt{n} / \sqrt{n})$.

Comment: So basically if $n = p_1^{r_1} \cdot ... \cdot p_m^{r_m}$  is the prime decomposition of $n$. You are looking for the value $\sum_{i=1}^m r_i$ ?

Comment: How can you that the sum is the number of primes smaller than $\sqrt(n)$? The PNT says that this is $O(\sqrt(n)/\log\sqrt (n))$...

Comment: Yes Zubzub, but from it can you derive $\Omega(n)$ is asymptotic to $\log\log n $?

Comment: You can't find an estimate for $f(n) = \sum_{p^k | n, k \ge 2} 1$ (it is chaotic) but you can find an upper bound, and a good estimate (using the Mertens theorem) for $\sum_{n \le x} f(n) = \sum_{p^k \le N, k \ge 2}\lfloor x/p^k \rfloor$

Comment: For Martens theorem di you mean the estimate for $\sum_{p<x}1/p$?

Answer (score 1):

Your sum has average value of approximately 0.77.  Following is a proof that the sum has an average value less than one.

My source of information comes mostly from Chapter 8 of I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \le x} \sum_{\substack{p^k | n\\ k \ge 2}} 1 & = \sum_{\substack{p^k,\ m\\ p^km \le x\\ k \ge 2}} 1 &&\text{($n = p^km$)}\\
& = \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x\\ k \ge 2}} \left\lfloor \frac x{p^k} \right\rfloor\\
& = \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x\\ k \ge 2}} \left( \frac x{p^k} + O(1) \right)\\
& = x \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x\\ k \ge 2}} \frac 1{p^k} + O\left( \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x\\ k \ge 2}} 1 \right)\\
& = x \sum_{\substack{p \le x^{1/k}\\ k \ge 2}} \frac 1{p^k} + O\left( \sum_{\substack{p \le x^{1/k}\\ k \ge 2}} 1 \right)\\
& \le x \sum_{\substack {p\\ k \ge 2}} \frac 1{p^k} + O\left( \sum_{k \ge 2} \pi\left(x^{1/k}\right) \right) &&\text{($\pi$ is the prime-counting function)}\\
& = x \sum_p \frac 1{p(p-1)} + O(\sqrt x \log x) &&\text{(sum of the geometric series)}\\
& \le x \sum_{j = 2}^\infty \frac 1{j(j-1)} + O(\sqrt x \log x)\\
& = x + O(\sqrt x \log x) &&\text{(the sum equals $1$)}
\end{align}
That shows that the coefficient of $x$ in the line before the first inequality is less than one.  Thus, your sum has an average value less than one.

To check that conclusion, I fit a line to $f(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{p^k | n, k \ge 2} 1 = \sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \omega(n))$ versus $x$ for $x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 100000$ and got $f(x) \approx 0.7725x - 45.00$ and, if the intercept is forced to be zero, $f(x) \approx 0.7718x$, both with coefficient of determination greater than $0.9999997$.  The arithmetic average of those $\Omega(x) - \omega(x)$ is approximately $0.7721$.

That explains why the average value of $\Omega(n)$ is $\log \log n$, the same as that of $\omega(n)$. $\Omega(n)$ is equal to $\omega(n)$ plus contributions from higher powers of $p$, but we have just shown that those contributions are of [normal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) (because the [average order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) that we determined is for a non-negative function) less than $\log \log n$.

See also [Martin Klazar's lecture notes "Introduction to Number Theory,"](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~klazar/ln_utc.pdf) Section 4.3.

Comment: You may wish to add a note that for a non-negative function, small average order implies small normal order.